# Obtaining scatter plot matrix of residuals

Tags: r

I wish to draw a scatter plot matrix of residuals in R for a longitudinal data analysis.

I wrote the given codes:

```
head(LungCapData2)
```

The data reads as follows:

```
     Age LungCap Height Gender Smoke
 1   9   3.124   57.0   female no
 2   8   3.172   67.5 female   no 
 3   7   3.160   54.5 female   no 
 4   9   2.674   53.0   male   no 
 5   9   3.685   57.0   male   no 
 6   8   5.008   61.0 female   no
```

I start to obtain the residuals using OLS:

```
lm1 <- lm(LungCap~Height, data=LungCapData)
lm1res<- resid(lm1)
roundht <- round(LungCapData2$Height)
Lung<-reshape(LungCapData2[c("Age","lm1res","roundht")],
          direction="wide",v.names="lm1res", timevar="roundht",idvar="Age")
```

The problem is with last piece of  code for reshaping it into the matrix. I wish to get a scatter plot by

```
pairs(Lung)
```

But my Lung data is as follows:

```
head(Lung)
  Age
1   9
2   8
3   7
4   6
5   5
6   4
  lm1res.c(57, 68, 54, 53, 61, 58, 56, 60, 50, 59, 62, 49, 52, 48, 65, 66, 55, 51, 69, 63, 64, 47, 46, 70, 72, 71, 67, 74, 73)
1
```

Cant figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: what output do you expect? you have 646 unique `lm1res` values do you want to have 646 variables?

Comment: I wish to plot a scatter plot of those 646 residuals at different height. I should get a graph with plots lmres-57, lmres-68,...

Comment: but your `lm1res` values have a range from -6 to +6

Answer (score 1):

Need to assign lmres and roundht to dataframe columns as you then refer to dataframe in reshape :

```
    LungCapData$lm1res<- resid(lm1)
    LungCapData$roundht <- round(LungCapData$Height)
    Lung<-reshape(LungCapData[c("Age","lm1res","roundht")],
                  direction="wide", v.names="lm1res",timevar="roundht",idvar="Age")
    pairs(Lung)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to see to it. But its still not working. Anyways, I tried the same line code for another set of data and it works finely. So, no worry, I changed my data set.